# Calculating Detours based on given blocked roads with Leaflet?

Tags: leaflet, routing

Is it possible to use a given route of "blocked roads" and calculate a route from A to B, considering that the given route is off limits using Leaflet?

Where I'm from, there is an annual bicycle sports event and many roads will be blocked for the racers to drive on. So I want to calculate detours based on blocked roads.

[image]

I want to calculate routes with Leaflets Routing and if the calculated route crosses a blocked road I want to calculate a detour if possible.

Comment: You can use the block_area feature from GraphHopper: https://github.com/graphhopper/graphhopper/blob/master/docs/web/api-doc.md#flexible. You'll need a server running in the background. Note: I'm one of the authors

Comment: @Karussell your comment looks like it may be worth you writing as an answer.